# Nutch 1.6 find original url of redirected ones

Tags: java, nutch, redirect

I wonder how could I find the original url after it hits a redirection. They're actually found on seedlist but I can not guarantee which url is redirected to which url.  In Fetcher phase I expect to read it from Nutch.WRITABLE_REPR_URL_KEY, but it is overriden by redirected url.

Any suggestion how to read them from crawldb, segments or linkdb?

PS: I only crawl first-level pages (depth:1) on seedlist.

Best,
Tugcem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump the outlinks by doing the following

```
bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl/segments/segmentname/ outputdir -nocontent -nofetch -    nogenerate -noparse -noparsetext
```

Also to properly follow the redirects, you might want to change this property in nutch-default.xml

```
<property>
<name>http.redirect.max</name>
<value>5</value>
<description>The maximum number of redirects the fetcher will follow when
trying to fetch a page. If set to negative or 0, fetcher won't immediately
follow redirected URLs, instead it will record them for later fetching.
</description>
</property>
```